# Is there a way to automatically push svn configuration settins from the server to the clients?

Tags: svn, administration, hook

Is there a way to force the client to update its local svn configuration using a hook?

I have lin and win clients and I'd like to push down a standard set of ignores and auto props.  Today, I provide a config files and ask the users to install them (.reg file for win and conf file for linux).  I'd like to flush them down to the clients automagically.

Is there a way to do this?   (I think not, but I had to ask because it would be nicer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you want is possible. However, see whether [this script](http://subversion.tigris.org/tools_contrib.html#pre_commit_check_py) helps.

Comment: Thanks, you all are basically in the same vein.  I thought of using a hook script but was concerned that it would merely be a major annoyance.   I had also considered a nag after the fact script.

either:
commit with wrong props
svn blocks commit with instructions on how to fix

or

commit with wrong props
svn allows
svn sends email with instructions to fix

Answer (score 1):

there is no build-in solution in subversion. However, you can write a pre-commithook script to examine the properties of your files.

There is already such a script in a project called **mr-ats** on [mr-ats.tigris.org](http://mr-ats.tigris.org)

http://guest:@mr-ats.tigris.org/svn/mr-ats/trunk/src/hooks/property-check/

However I did't used it yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can push registry settings to Windows users logged on a Domain via Group Policy. You can also set a config file in the 'all users' location (E.g. /etc, /usr/local/etc or C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Tigris\Subversion).